# Can't disable TLSv1 and RC4-SHA

Tags: centos, security, apache-httpd, ssl

I need to remove TLSv1 and RC4-SHA support in Centos 7.

I have these lines in my ssl.conf

```
SSLProtocol +TLSv1.2 +TLSv1.1 -TLSv1
SSLCompression off
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCipherSuite "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA"
```

And I am checking if RC4 and TLSv1 are still supported using this command

```
sslscan --no-failed xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1337
```

sslscan gave me this result:

```
Supported Server Cipher(s):

Accepted  TLSv1  256 bits  AES256-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1  256 bits  CAMELLIA256-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  AES128-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  CAMELLIA128-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  DES-CBC3-SHA
**Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  RC4-SHA**
Accepted  TLS11  256 bits  AES256-SHA
Accepted  TLS11  256 bits  CAMELLIA256-SHA
Accepted  TLS11  128 bits  AES128-SHA
Accepted  TLS11  128 bits  CAMELLIA128-SHA
Accepted  TLS11  128 bits  DES-CBC3-SHA
**Accepted  TLS11  128 bits  RC4-SHA**
Accepted  TLS12  256 bits  AES256-GCM-SHA384
Accepted  TLS12  256 bits  AES256-SHA256
Accepted  TLS12  256 bits  AES256-SHA
Accepted  TLS12  256 bits  CAMELLIA256-SHA
Accepted  TLS12  128 bits  AES128-GCM-SHA256
Accepted  TLS12  128 bits  AES128-SHA256
Accepted  TLS12  128 bits  AES128-SHA
Accepted  TLS12  128 bits  CAMELLIA128-SHA
Accepted  TLS12  128 bits  DES-CBC3-SHA
**Accepted  TLS12  128 bits  RC4-SHA**
```

Apparently RC4-SHA is still accepted which I am trying to configure to not support any RC4 and TLSv1. Is there a way of resolving this?

Comment: Two things spring to mind - Have you restarted the service? Have you an additional `SSLProtocol` and/or `SSLCipherSuite` line in a config file of a virtual host that overrides the one in `ssl.conf`?

Comment: There are none.

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration works when I use it in a newly setup virtual host on both Apache v2.2 and v2.4. So I'm afraid you must be doing something else wrong.

1. You didn't restart Apache
2. The URL you are testing is wrong somehow
3. You have conflicting configuration you didn't find (as @garethTheRed mentioned)

I suggest you do the following:

1. Run a full stop/start for apache (making sure Apache is not running inbetween), just to be sure of your running configuration
2. Run `apachectl -S` and verify your virtual hosts. Put the output in your question if you are unsure.
3. Setup a new bare bones SSL virtualhost and test that to make sure everything is ok

I would also suggest changing the cipher list to something more secure, such as

`SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH`

This cipher list was taken from https://cipherli.st/